# Pivot Table Excel Grand Total Shows the Sum of Unformulated Calculated Field Value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I tried a simple data table,

Table 1

| ITEM | TARGET |
| --- | --- |
| A | 150 |
| B | 150 |

Table 2

| ITEM | PROD_QTY |
| --- | --- |
| A | 160 |
| B | 120 |

I append both of the tables and create a Pivot Table, then use calculated field to see the outstanding by using these formula:

```
=IF(TARGET-PROD_QTY<=0;0;TARGET-PROD_QTY)
```

It worked well with the sum of outstanding, but when I was see the grand total, it shows like this:

| ITEM | SUM OF OUTSTANDING |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 30 |
| **Grand Total** | **20** |

Is there anything that I could do to fix the grand total?
Cause I think the Grand Total is ignoring the =IF function in Calculated field and just go straight to the calculation

Comment: Not sure I understand. Grand Totals do not by default sum the individual entries. They apply the same calculation as for the individual entries, but for all entries. So here 300-280=20 is perfectly consistent and expected behaviour. If you want to override this you'll need to use a measure within Power Pivot.

Comment: I see, I am not aware of how the pivot grand total works, since I'm a beginner in pivot table. I'll learn about the measure thing and Power Pivot. Thank you for the pointer

Comment: Ok, if you need help with the measure just reply here.